# Can a string user input somehow be a non string or null type?

Tags: dart, validation, console-application, user-input

I am asking for a user input, and it has to be a String and not null afterall.

Can somehow an user enter a non string value or null? so I would be force to validate it?
or I can safely skip this validation code? (since it is redundat)

```
String? userInput = stdin.readLineSync();

if (userInput != null){
  if (userInput.runtimeType == String){
    print('Validated input');
  } else{ // if is not a string
    print('You did not entered a string');
  }
  print('You entered a null value'); // if null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should, in general, not use `.runtimeType` in production code. E.g. in your example it would be better to use `if (userInput is String)` to test if `userInput` are compatible with the `String` type. The difference is that we often don't care about exact types but rather if something is just compatible with a given type.

Next, the `stdin.readLineSync()` is defined to return `String?` which means it is enforced by the type system to return a `String` or `null`. It can't return e.g. a number.

So your `if (userInput != null)` is actually enough since if this is the case, we know for a fact that `userInput` must then be a `String`.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  String? userInput = stdin.readLineSync();

  if (userInput != null){
    print('Validated input. Input must be a String.');
  } else {
    print('You entered a null value by closing the input stream!');
  }
}
```

For when `userInput` can become `null`, it happens if the user are closing stdin input stream. You can do that in `bash` (and in other terminals) by using Ctrl+D keyboard shortcut. If doing so, the `userInput` would become `null`.